# Execute the procedure error "ORA-00911: invalid character"

Tags: oracle, procedure

I create the new procedure to update the wrong sql field from the DB table `(po_headers_all)` and the table field `(ATTRIBUTE2)`. 
Then, when I try to execute the procedure, the error to show **"ORA-00911: invalid character"**

Running the script in the DB environment: **ORACLE 12C**

```
 procedure update_epo_attribute2 (epo_num NUMBER, P_ORG_ID NUMBER) IS

BEGIN

 UPDATE apps.po_headers_all
 SET ATTRIBUTE2 = 'Contract'
   WHERE  ATTRIBUTE2 = 'Perm'
     AND segment1 = EPO_NUM
     AND org_id = P_ORG_ID
     AND segment1 IN (SELECT poh.segment1
                        FROM   apps.po_requisition_headers_all prh,
                               apps.po_requisition_lines_all prl, 
                               apps.po_req_distributions_all prd,
                               apps.po_headers_all poh,
                               apps.po_distributions_all pda       
                        WHERE prh.requisition_header_id = prl.requisition_header_id
                          AND prh.type_lookup_code = 'PURCHASE'
                          AND prd.requisition_line_id = prl.requisition_line_id
                          AND pda.req_distribution_id (+) = prd.distribution_id
                          AND pda.po_header_id = poh.po_header_id (+)
                          AND poh.ATTRIBUTE2 = 'Perm'
                          AND prl.SUGGESTED_VENDOR_LOCATION = 'CONTRACT');

commit;

end;
```

Then, the below of executing the procedure script in ORACLE form control:

```
='declare
   begin
    PO_ETL.update_epo_attribute2 ('''||${item.PO_HEADERS.SEGMENT1.VALUE}||''','''||$${item.PO_HEADERS.ORG_ID.VALUE}||''');
  end'
```

The result is fail and show the error message **"ORA-00911: invalid character"**.

Comment: You don't need/want `declare` as you aren't declaring anything, just start from `begin`; and the `end` needs a semicolon. Neither of which should be relevant to the error. I'm not familiar with exactly how you're executing this, but assuming the general pattern is right, what do your embedded variables actually resolve to - can you debug the full generated statement (anonymous block)? Is the second variable reference really supposed to have `$$`? And why are you embedding those values in (escaped) single quotes when they're supposed to be numbers? And can they be bind variables instead?

Comment: You could debug your error by debugging/ print out the dynamic sql string and check if it's a valid procedure call. One possible error maybe that the procedure get 2 number as params, but you call it with 2 varchar2 values, and one of them cannot be implicitly convert to number type.

Comment: Hi, Pham. Thanks for your comments. Your solution is correct. Thanks for your help.